# Detecção de cores quentes na imagem em Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, processamento-de-imagens

Estou com um problema e preciso da ajuda de vocês.

Possuo uma série de imagens termográficas, das quais preciso detectar o ponto quente (apresentado na barra a direita da imagem) na área em que esta sendo feita a análise. No caso destas imagens exemplo, o ponto quente está no foco da mira, porém, o objetivo é imaginar que não sei onde esta este ponto e que o próprio algoritmo encontre ele, baseando-se na barra a direita. Deixo abaixo uma destas imagens como exemplo:

[image: IR_1544.jpg]

Neste exemplo, a barra lateral me indica uma faixa de temperatura entre 33.2 e 97.7 °C.
Gostaria de identificar na imagem onde está o ponto de 97.7 °C.
Inicialmente criei um código em que leio o valor BGR no ponto mais alto da barra e procuro esta combinação no restante da imagem, isto não me retornou nada.
Não convencido, criei um código que identifica o código RGB em toda a barra e procura na imagem, o que também não retornou nada, o código segue abaixo:

```
# Find one of temperature bar colors in the image
import cv2
image_path = r"C:\Users\bruno\PycharmProjects\TCC\Imagens\IR_1544.jpg"

img = cv2.imread(image_path)
crop1 = img[69:171, 309:310]

for i in range(70, 172):
    crop = img[i-1:i, 309:310]
    num1, num2, num3 = cv2.split(crop)
    for i in range(0, crop.shape[0]):
        for j in range(0, crop.shape[1]):
            if img[i][j][0] == num1:
                if img[i][j][1] == num2:
                    if img[i][j][2] == num3:
                        print("I found")

cv2.imshow("img1", img)
cv2.imshow("img2", crop1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Gostaria de saber se existe outra forma que eu possa identificar estas cores na imagem.
Agradeço a todos que puderem ajudar!!

Comment: Possui a imagem sem estas informações do software da FLIR?

Comment: Não possuo, a princípio as imagens que terei que processar sempre terão estas informações :(

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que você queira identificar a 'maior temperatura' na imagem, e levando em consideração que o ponto (pixel) mais claro da imagem será igual ao ponto (pixel) mais claro da barra:

1. Converter para Gray Scale
2. Aplicar cv2.GaussianBlur para suavizar os pixels e remover ruído. Aqui o segredo é ajustar o kernel (35x35) de acordo com sua aplicação. Quanto maior o kernel, maior será a área de 'suavização'.
3. Chama cv2.minMaxLoc, que retorna uma tupla com a posição do pixel mais intenso da imagem. [3]

Sugestão:

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("imagem.jpeg")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (35, 35), 0)
(_, _, _, maxIntense) = cv2.minMaxLoc(gray)

cv2.circle(image, maxIntense, 2, (0, 0, 0), 1)
cv2.rectangle(image, (maxIntense[0]-10, maxIntense[1]+10), (maxIntense[0]+10, maxIntense[1]-10), (0,0,0), 1)

cv2.imshow("Imagem", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Agradeço bastante as dicas. Eu já havia conseguido fazer, conforme a resposta presente aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61599703/detecting-warm-colors-in-the-python-image. De qualquer forma bate bastante com a tua resposta, muito obrigado!